# How to login as superuser\administrator in Scientific Linux 6 LiveCD?

Tags: root, non-root-user, livecd, scientific-linux

I have a LiveCD started as a default user. How to login as root?

[Here](http://www.livecd.ethz.ch/parameter.html) it is said that there are boot parameters. How and when to set them?

Comment: Have you tried just using `su`? Most of the time the default user on a livecd has passwordless `sudo`, and can also `su` passwordlessly to any other user.

Comment: @ParthianShot: yes! It works! Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just using [`su`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su)?

Most of the time the default user on a livecd has passwordless [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), and can also `su` passwordlessly to any other user.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these:

1. [Usage](http://www.livecd.ethz.ch/usage.html)
2. [Boot parameters](http://www.livecd.ethz.ch/parameter.html)

`pw=any_password` :  set a password for root and local user